# R HydroTSM how to import precipitation data from csv

Tags: r, csv, data-import

I'm new to R coding and got this issue:

I have created a csv file that reads like

id,Prec
1966-01-01,4.6
1966-01-02,7.9
1966-01-03,0.1
1966-01-04,6.3
1966-01-05,8.8
1966-01-06,7.5
1966-01-07,0
1966-01-08,0.5
1966-01-09,0.2

where id is the date.

How can i import this data into R for use with hydrotsm?

I'm trying to get data for use with this example, but for my own data:

1. Loading the hydroTSM library, which contains data and functions used in this analysis.

> library(hydroTSM)
>
> Loading daily precipitation data at the station San Martino di Castrozza, Trento Province, Italy, with data
>   from 01/Jan/1921 to 31/Dec/1990.
>   data(SanMartinoPPts)
>
> Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the vignette hydroTSM_Vignette.pdf.  If you type in data(SanMartinoPPts) at the R prompt, you will have the San Martino di Castrozza data loaded into your R session.

If you are trying to load your own data, which is in csv format, check out ?read.csv. 
Note that if you take the first 6 lines of the San Martino data:

```
SMPPts <- head(SanMartinoPPts)
```

and write it to .csv:

```
write.csv(SMPPts, "SMPPts.csv")
```

and then open SMPPts.csv, it will look like this:

```
            x
1921-01-01  0
1921-01-02  0
1921-01-03  4
1921-01-04  0
1921-01-05  0
1921-01-06  0
```

This is how time series data should look in .csv format before you load it into R, as opposed to the example you showed which is all one line separated by commas and tabs. Because it is time series data, the row names are the dates and there is no need for "id".

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to import your data from Excel like this:

```
Data<- read.csv("YOURFILE.CSV", header = TRUE, sep = ";",dec = "."); # Read from CSV file
```

Now you have to create a ZOO object because the most of hydroTSM functions use this class.

```
library(zoo)

Datazoo<- zoo(Data[,2],Data[,1]) # Data[,2] is the values and Data[,1] is the index data
```

Comment: `SanMartinoPPts` is a zoo object with `"Date"` class time index. To read in a csv file of the form shown in the question creating a zoo object with `"Date"` class time index note that loading hydroTSM automatically loads zoo so this works: `library(hydroTSM); z <- read.zoo("myfile.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")` .  Read `?read.zoo` and see the vignette, Reading Data in zoo, which gives numerous `read.zoo` examples: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html